# Python: Median of a list of numbers

Tags: python, pyscripter

When I run my program on PyScripter, I get the expected median of `4.5`. But running the same code on [Ideone as here](http://ideone.com/OrLAXQ) or on [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-rCQKw/0/1) returns `4`. Any idea why the different results? Thanks.

```
#Create a function that returns the median of a list of numbers
def median(list_of_numbers):

#Make a copy of list_of_numbers and sort the new list
    lst = list_of_numbers
    lst = sorted(lst)

#Get the length of list and use it to index through the list
    lst_length = len(lst)
    index = int(lst_length/2)

#If length if even, average the two middle numbers
    if lst_length%2==0:
        a=  lst[index-1]
        b = lst[index]
        result = (a+b)/2

#If length is odd, return the middle number
    else:
        result = lst[index]
    return result

print (median([4, 5, 5, 4]))
```

My PyScripter version: *** Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***

Comment: In py2 `/` is floor division and in py3 `/` is float division. Try replacing `2` by `2.`.

Comment: What if you try `//` instead of `/`?
Eg: `int(lst_length//2)`

Comment: As @Hyperboreus suggested, replace the line `result = (a+b)/2` with `(a+b)/2.`. Changing `2` to `2.` (or `2.0`) casts it as float, returning always a floating division. In python2 by default `/` stands for integer division (if both `a` and `b` are integer), in python 3 it is by default a floating point division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 2.x you will need to replace both occurrences of `2` by `2.` in order to enforce floating point division.

Your link to ideone is Python 2.x and apparently so is your codeacademy interpreter.

Comment: alternatively you can add `from __future__ import division` at the front of the script

Answer (score 0):

```
import statistics as s

def mid(data):
    return(int(s.median(data)))

middle = mid([3,4,6,3,12,6,45,32,78])
print(middle)
```

I'd use the statistics module. If you want your output to be an integer or a float, just cast it (float() or int() respectively).